# Use RxAndroid or RxKotlin when programming in Kotlin for Android?

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-kotlin

I am going to start using reactive programming in my Android project. I am using Kotlin as primary language and now I would like to apply Rx. My first choice was RxAndroid but then I noticed that there is RxKotlin.

As far as I know both are forked from RxJava so RxAndroid probably provides some API for android common tasks. On the other hand RxKotlin support lambas out of the box and allow me avoiding mixing kotlin with java.

Which one is preferred library in that case?

Comment: Downvoters, please write what is wrong with my question? I will improve it if necessary.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could use both of them. 
**[RxKotlin](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin)** contains an [extension functions](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) that provides to you idiomatic way(with writing less code) of using [**rxJava**](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) in Kotlin.
**rxAndroid**(is now split in few libraries) provides specific platform bindings such as:

- *[rxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid)* that could help you to manage an execution with native android [Handlers](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/Handler.html)
- *[rxLifecycle](https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle)* that provides Activity lifecycle bindings
- *[rxBinding and rxBinding-kotlin](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding)* that helps to manage UI with all power of rxJava

There are few more useful [libraries for rxJava and Android](https://github.com/zsoltk/RxAndroidLibs) you could be interested.

**Edited 01.04.16**

Comment: @Stone thanks for answer. Could you please write a little bit more about those rxkotlin advantages? RxKotlin wiki is very poor.

Comment: @DamianPetla the entire rxkotlin library is convenience utility extension functions.